# How to stop a WebView launched from SL4A from hiding the notification bar?

Tags: android, python, android-webview, sl4a

I'm building a UI for my little Python SL4A script that uses WebViews, but I find a little annoying that when I launch my WebView from the SL4A script (droid.webViewShow(...)) the Android notification bar gets hidden!

Here's some code:

```
import android

droid = android.Android()
droid.webViewShow('file:///sdcard/sl4a/scripts/sample.html')
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? Any parameter or configuration I'm missing?

Comment: By the way I've tried to launch the WebView from Python and JavaScript and I get the same behavior on both.

Comment: Please add more code for me to understand the problem properly.

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN that is all the code! this is a python app on SL4A that is all the code you need to launch a WebView

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to re-architect your solution a bit.  I would recommend you layout.xml file define the webview and the area of which it resides.  In your manifest, you can define if the activity is a fullscreen activity or not, and lastly, you would instantiate it from your client code and render into the current activity.

Try taking a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html to get an idea for proper architecture.

If I'm misinterpreted your question, you might consider posting additional code so there is a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but you probably didn't read the full question, this is a SL4A (Scripting Layer for Android) app, there's no manifest and there are no activities, the tutorial you're linking to is in Java and I'm working on Python.